# I transfer in a link a string like this : baltus & adang. How can i keep that together

Tags: php, uri

In th title i asp if i transfer a string like baltus & adang. In u link i have a variable named $NameString. This string is filled with the value 'Baltus & Adang' . When i passed it to the a second module with &NameString= Baltus & Adang? is see the when i do a $NameString=    $_GET["NameString"]; the value is still baltus & adang. When i passed it to a thrid module and i do also : $NameString=    $_GET["NameString"]; is see only Baltus.

What to do to correct it?
Thanks,
Fred

i did all kind of things..

You can see it if you go to https://fred-baltus.nl/api and type in **baltus & adang** in the search field. On the next screen click on a link. On the third screen when you hover over **Terug** you see that NaamString only contains **baltus**

Comment: You [urlencode](https://www.php.net/urlencode) it, because `&` is a special character.

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried and how you're trying to get the NameString between modules?

Comment: If you did `var_dump($_GET)` in your third module, you'd see `array(2) {
  ["NameString"]=>
  string(6) "Baltus",
  ["Adang"]=>
  string(0) ""
}` without url-encoding the `&` ampersand that separates URL variables.

Comment: In the second and third module i use:
<code>

$NaamString=    $_GET["NaamString"]; 
$EventType=     $_GET["EventType"]; 
$RelationType=  $_GET["RelationType"]; 
$lang =         $_GET["lang"];
$ArchiveCode =  $_GET["ArchiveCode"] ;
$SourceType  =  $_GET["SourceType"] ;
$Identifier =   $_GET["Identifier"] ;
$PersonName =   $_GET["PersonName"] ;
$start=         $_GET["start"];

.....
  $linkterug = '<a href="showgen.php?NaamString='.$NaamString.'&lang=nl&start='.$start.'"';
</code>

Comment: Thanks to you all. urlencode helps! That was the problem. And i saw i had it also in the second module. Now i have to look for a nicer pagination module.